# Is it obligatory to mock useState hooks with Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Is it an obligation to mock `useState` hooks with Jest and Enzyme? Because it's complicated to do for a simple component.

Is Enzyme's `simulate` function working in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only obligations you have are to whatever product you're building, your business requirements, your customer and your team. You don't have any obligations imposed by Enzyme, certainly. You can use Enzyme just fine without mocking `useState`.

I'd go a step further and suggest not mocking `useState` in general, assuming that's OK with your team and makes sense for your product. The reason is that `useState` is an implementation detail the user doesn't care about and isn't integral to the business specification or functionality of the component. Changing between `useState` and another type of state management shouldn't break your behavioral tests.

At the time of writing, Enzyme (along with its invasive, 100% line-coverage philosophy) is generally being phased out in favor of [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) and its "don't test implementation details" philosophy. Unlike Enzyme, RTL doesn't facilitate digging into components' state and lifecycle and encourages tests to rely on the UI and props to manipulate components.

The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#overview) currently suggests using RTL and the black box approach to testing:

> We recommend using React Testing Library which is designed to enable and encourage writing tests that use your components as the end users do.

[Elsewhere](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing.html), it says:

> React Testing Library is a set of helpers that let you test React components without relying on their implementation details. This approach makes refactoring a breeze and also nudges you towards best practices for accessibility.

Kent Dodds has a great blog post on [testing implementation details](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details) which provides concrete examples of why the Enzyme philosophy can be dangerous. It all boils down to avoiding "the test user" -- an imaginary client of the app that is a poor substitute to actual users (who will use the UI) and programmers (who will use APIs to interface with modules). Unchecked, the test user tends to make demands on your tests like 100% code coverage and mocked state and lifecycle that don't necessarily relate to the functionality or behavior of the component.

---

Regarding `simulate` -- I'm not sure what your use case is, but it should work fine without state mocks since it's used to fire events on elements, triggering your component's event handlers.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read the different philosophies and approaches of different test libraries, I am not still used to it